# Styling data of array

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

```
<%= @referral1 = User.joins(:reviews).select(' users.name, 
count(reviews.id) as count')
.group('users.name')
.group_by { |r| r["count"] }
.sort_by  { |k, v| -k }
.first(4)                    
%>
```

This is the code I'm using and getting data from database. The results are

```
[[1560, [#<User id: nil, name: "Carolanne Maggio">]], [15, [#<User id: nil, name: "test9">]], [8, [#<User id: nil, name: "josh">]], [4, [#<User id: nil, name: "test">]]]
```

I wanted to get the top users with most number of reviews with their number of reviews. 
The query is giving me so, but now I want to show this data in a proper way. 
Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: What is your question ? what  do you mean by proper way ?

Comment: I want to make two columns in front of each other. One of User and other for number of reviews by that user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate the `@referral1` object and use the data from there, maybe something like this

```
<% @referral1 = User.joins(:reviews).select(' users.name, 
  count(reviews.id) as count')
  .group('users.name')
  .group_by { |r| r["count"] }
  .sort_by  { |k, v| -k }
  .first(4)                    
%> 

<table>
  <th>User</th><th>Reviews</th>
  <tbody>
    <% @referral1.each do |referral| %>
      <tr><td><%= referral[0] %></td><td><%= referral[1].name %></td></tr>
    <% end %>          
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Hope this helps.

**BTW** your query seems really inefficient, if you could show your models and their relationships, I could help simplify it.

Comment: This giving me this error:  undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I'm a real noob in rails. I just want the styling for my data. Nothing else

Comment: will you update your question with the code you are using and the full error stack trace

Comment: The code in my question gives me the results that I've shown in question as well. I don't know how to apply styling on my results.

Comment: This was what I needed, thank you. But with "referral[0]" and "referral[1].name" I am not getting any results. I made different variables for reviews count and username and showed results by using flat_map(&: ). But I am unable to remove  User id: nil from result. Is there any way to remove it? Also I want to show user names and reviews count's each value separately not in parentheses.

Comment: what data are you getting after using `flat_map(&:)` ?

Comment: With `flat_map(&: first)` I am getting review count and with `flat_map(&: last)` I am getting this data [[#<User id: nil, name: "Carolanne Maggio">, #<User id: nil, name: "test9">, #<User id: nil, name: "josh">, #<User id: nil, name: "test">]].

Comment: Can you upload your project on github or any other source from where I can pull it down and have a look